# CLASS MATH -- Need Help getting an Int Value from XY -- Super Lost

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, integer, label

Okay, so I am been learning python for 2 weeks and implementing TkInter now, I am trying to make an project where the user can set an Alarm and when the alarm rings the user will hit stop then the program will ask the user some random math questions, I been messing around and got everything up to the Math problem to work, I have a lot of placeholders in place and I am stuck with getting the answer of x and y to return to an INT, I have it made where it will show what x+y will equal and what the user enter but when I run the while loop my program just freezes. I assume its because the answer returns as a Label and that's not an INT, so all my issues are in my Math Class and have been trying for 3 days and cant figure it out. Please anything will be helpful, I tried using the .get method but that also gives me errors.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time
import datetime
from tkinter import *
from winsound import PlaySound, SND_FILENAME, SND_LOOP, SND_ASYNC
import random


class WakeUpApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='true',)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=400, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=250, weight=2)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Alarm, Chooser, Difficulty, Math):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


        self.show_frame(Alarm)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()





present = datetime.datetime.now()
now = present.strftime("%H:%M:%S")


class Alarm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        Alarm.hour = tk.StringVar()
        Alarm.min = tk.StringVar()
        Alarm.sec = tk.StringVar()

        hour_a = tk.Entry(self, text=Alarm.hour, width=4).place(x=50, y=50)
        min_a = tk.Entry(self, text=Alarm.min, width=4).place(x=70, y=50)
        sec_a = tk.Entry(self, text=Alarm.sec, width=4).place(x=90, y=50)

        current_time = tk.Label(self, text=f'Current Time:  {now}').place(x=0, y=30)
        set_time = tk.Label(self, text='Set Time').place(x=0, y=50)

        '''
        VERY IMPORTANT -- THIS CODE STARTS THE ALARM
        
        setalarm = tk.Button(self, text='Set Alarm', command=lambda: wake())
        setalarm.place(x=90, y=90)
        
        '''

        setalarm = tk.Button(self, text='Set Alarm', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Chooser))
        setalarm.place(x=90, y=90)


        def wake():
            alarm_time = f'{Alarm.hour.get()}:{Alarm.min.get()}:{Alarm.sec.get()}'
            alarm_clock(alarm_time)


        def play_sound(self,):
            PlaySound('Sound.wav', SND_FILENAME|SND_LOOP|SND_ASYNC)
        def stop_sound(self):
            PlaySound(None, SND_FILENAME)


        def alarm_clock(alarm_time):

            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                present = datetime.datetime.now()
                now = present.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                print(now)
                if now == alarm_time:
                    break

            if now == alarm_time:
                play_sound(self)
                testbutton = Button(self, text='pls work', command=lambda: stop_sound(self))
                testbutton.pack()



class Chooser(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Please Choose Your Wake Up Game')
        label.pack(pady=50, padx=50)
        math = tk.Button(self, text='Math Game',
                         height=5, width=15,
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Difficulty))
        math.place(x=125, y=75)
        guesser = tk.Button(self, text='Guessing Game',
                         height=5, width=15,
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Alarm))
        guesser.place(x=125, y=175)

class Difficulty(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Please Choose Your Difficulty for the Questions')
        label.pack(pady=50, padx=50)

        level1 = tk.Button(self, text='Level 1 \n ie: 12+17',
                         height=5, width=15,
                         command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Math))
        level1.place(x=125, y=75)

        level2 = tk.Button(self, text='Level 2 \n ie: 12*9',
                           height=5, width=15,
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Alarm))
        level2.place(x=125, y=175)

        level3 = tk.Button(self, text='Level 3 \n ie: 6*7+21',
                           height=5, width=15,
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Alarm))
        level3.place(x=125, y=275)



class Math(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        x = tk.IntVar()
        y = tk.IntVar()
        z = tk.IntVar()
        ab = tk.IntVar()

        x = random.randint(1, 10)
        y = random.randint(1, 10)

        xy = int(x + y)

        problem = tk.Label(self, text=f'{x} + {y}').place(x=0, y=30)
        goal = tk.Label(self, text=xy).place(x=0, y=90)

        solution = tk.Entry(self, text=z).place(x=0, y=50)
        new = tk.Entry(self, text=ab).place(x=0, y=70)


        def answer2(self):
            py_guess = tk.Label(self, text=ab.get()).place(x=125, y=120)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text='GIVE ME Z PLS', command=lambda: answer())
        button2.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text='The Problem', command=lambda: answer2(self))
        button2.pack()


        def answer():
            user_guess = tk.Label(self, text=z.get()).place(x=125, y=100)
            level1(user_guess)

        def level1(user_guess):

            keepGoing = True

            while keepGoing:
                if (z == xy):
                    good = tk.Label(self, text='good job').pack()
                    keepGoing = False
                else:
                    bad = tk.Label(self, text='nope go again').pack()



       string_solution = solution.get()
       int_solution = int(string_solution)


app = WakeUpApp()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: Please provide [mre]. Also why are You defining functions inside `__init__`. `while` loops will interfere with tkinter's mainloop and it will never update unless You exit that loop, if You really need a loop (which I don't think You need for setting up labels) use [`.after()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/)